# React not rendering components from if else block

Tags: reactjs

The if/else statement is working. I have put console logs and debuggers in both parts of the conditionals. It hits each when it's supposed to. But the components are not being rendered. Here is the relevant code.

```
  handleUsers() {
    this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
      console.log(user, 'User')
      return <User {...user} key={user.name}/>
    })
  }

  handleVideos() {
    this.props.videos.map((video,index) => {
      return <Video videoId={this.handleModalPlay.bind(this)}
                key={index} {...video} />
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='main-body'>
        <div className='cards'>
          {this.props.videos.length === 0
           ? this.handleUsers()
           : this.handleVideos()}
        </div>
```

Previously, before trying to display other users, I had this piece of code and it would return and render as expected.

```
 render(){
    return(
      <div className='main-body'>
        <div className='cards'>
          {this.props.videos.map((video,index) => {
            return <Video videoId={this.handleModalPlay.bind(this)}
            key={index} {...video} />
          })}
        </div>
```

I'm not really sure why the components stopped rendering when the debuggers and console logs are showing that it's getting into the appropriate functions.

Comment: `handleUsers` and `handleVideos` should return something ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `handleUsers` and `handleVideos` functions. Put a return statement

```
handleUsers() {
    return this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
      console.log(user, 'User')
      return <User {...user} key={user.name}/>
    })
  }

  handleVideos() {
    return this.props.videos.map((video,index) => {
      return <Video videoId={this.handleModalPlay.bind(this)}
                key={index} {...video} />
    })
  }
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you :D Ya I'm newish to javaScript and thought that the return inside the iteration was enough. Thanks again!